# How is this bootstrap menu showing the drop down on hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a bit of trouble with the difference between my bootstrap theme for wordpress and my bootstrap theme for plain old web pages.

The main menu (topmost menu) on wordpress is showing perfectly, it is styled nice and everything drops down when you mouse over it...but on the main page it's a nightmare and shows on click only.

I've compared the CSS and JS files for both bootstraps and I can't find the reason why the WP one is showing on hover and allowing me to click the hover links and the regular one is not. The only differences between the files are colours. Can anyone please help me figure this out?

Wordpress menu: http://www.nextlevelsmf.com/news/

Regular menu (only this page): http://www.nextlevelsmf.com/testing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS styles have a selector of class `navbar-main` which is not present in your menu for non wordpress pages. Add this CSS:

```
.navbar li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
 display: block;
 -webkit-animation: fadeInUp 300ms;
   -moz-animation: fadeInUp 300ms;
   -ms-animation: fadeInUp 300ms;
   -o-animation: fadeInUp 300ms;
   animation: fadeInUp 300ms;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  color: #999;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu > li:hover > a,
.navbar .dropdown-menu > li:focus > a,
.navbar .dropdown-menu > li.active > a {
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu > li:last-child > a {
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu > li.divider {
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
}
.navbar li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInUp 300ms;
  -moz-animation: fadeInUp 300ms;
  -ms-animation: fadeInUp 300ms;
  -o-animation: fadeInUp 300ms;
  animation: fadeInUp 300ms;
}
.navbar .sub-menu .dropdown-menu {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

also a media query based on `navbar-right` is right aligning the dropdowns. Add this to fix:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
  right:0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: One more question...the whole menu is still shifted to the left...did I put the media part in the wrong spot or is there something else I missed? :)

Comment: Actually removing the media query fixes it :D. Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry it doesn't fix it, I must have been looking at something funny.

Comment: Got it, there was an opening bracket after the media query missing. Still new to those so I missed it. Thank you again, I really appreciate it!!

Comment: You're right oops! Copied it out of the chrome console which removes the opening and closing brackets on media queries. Glad you got it sorted.